# Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 on Dolphin Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, mobile-browser

I am sending a request to fetch xml response from server, for which I tried this simple piece of code in javascript

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    var req = "test.xml";
    xmlhttp.open("GET",req,false);
    xmlhttp.send();    //this line throws the error
```

Now, this works fine for desktop browsers and even on Android browser, but when I try it from browsers of some java phones, we get following error:

Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Note that the error is thrown by the last line of the 4 lines above and not when we call `new XMLHttprequest` or open the connection.

I've also tried `xmlhttp.send(null);` but no help

What could be the reason for send() failing?